# jQuery Delegate Event STILL not triggered for element in AngularJS template

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I know many posts are talking about using `jQuery Delegate Event` to solve the click event in AngularJS template, but that doesn't work for me at all:

**In my `app.js`:**

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function ($) {
   // My Angular code is here:
   // var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "firebase"])
   // Bla bla bla...

   $(".bordered-button-red .show-guide-button").on("click", function () {
       alert("Clicked!");
   });
})(jQuery);
```

I've even tried the following but none of them work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".bordered-button-red .show-guide-button", function () {
    alert("Clicked!");
});
```

While I thought my query selector was wrong, but below isn't working too:

```
// No space between .bordered-button-red and .show-guide-button    
$(".bordered-button-red.show-guide-button").on("click", function () {
    alert("Clicked!");
});
```

The following is my template:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div class="bordered-button-red show-guide-button">Show Guide</div>
   <p>Guide text...</p>

   <div class="bordered-button-red show-guide-button">Show Guide</div>
   <p>Different guide text...</p>

   <div class="bordered-button-red show-guide-button">Show Guide</div>
   <p>Another guide text...</p>

</div>
```

As you can see, I have multiple guide buttons and text of the same set, so I prefer to use jQuery (and not `ng-click` and `ng-show`) so that I can take advantage of `$(this)` and `.next()` as shown below:

```
$(".bordered-button-red .show-guide-button").on("click", function () {
    alert("Clicked!");
    
    if ($(this).text() == "Show Guide") {
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).text("Hide Guide");
    } else {
        $(this).next().hide();
        $(this).text("Show Guide");
    };
});
```

Using `ng-click` and `ng-show` are simply too much of work for such a simple task, especially when you also want to **add animation to the show/hide** as simple as that in jQuery: `show("slow")`. I tried to put inside `myCtrl` of `app.js` but not working either. Any idea how can I make my jQuery delegate event really work?

Thank you so much in advance!

**NOTE: No javascript error has been logged to console for any of the above trials.**

Comment: If you just want to achieve a show/hide effect, you really do not need to use jQuery.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @angel.bonev : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Have you tried to delegate the click event on body instead? Could be the document prevents bubbling.

Comment: @skobaljic : Work like a charm! I have posted the answer below! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As **@skobaljic** commented, delegate the click on `body` works:

```
$("body").on("click", ".bordered-button-red.show-guide-button", function () {
        alert("Clicked!");
        
        if ($(this).text() == "Show Guide") {
            $(this).next().show();
            $(this).text("Hide Guide");
        } else {
            $(this).next().hide();
            $(this).text("Show Guide");
        };
    });
```

But note that the jQuery selector **must not have space in between two classes**: `".bordered-button-red.show-guide-button"`. Thank you so much to **@skobaljic** again!